# Dynamically Assigning GA Enhanced Ecommerce tracker

Tags: javascript, json, google-tag-manager

I have the following javascript code where i want to assign the one of its value dynamically:

```
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'checkout',
    'ecommerce': {
        'checkout': {
            'actionField': {'step': 1, 'option': 'Visa'},
            'products': [{
                'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',
                'id': '12345',
                'price': '15.25',
                'brand': 'Google',
                'category': 'Apparel',
                'variant': 'Gray',
                'quantity': 1
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

I want to assign the content of 'product' dynamically by creating a new variable, so the final code would like like this :

```
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'checkout',
    'ecommerce': {
        'checkout': {
            'actionField': {'step': 1, 'option': 'Visa'},
            'products': my_new_array
        }
    }
});
```

I tried to do it using smarty so it looks like this :

```
{literal}
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'checkout',
    'ecommerce': {
        'checkout': {
            'actionField': {'step': 1, 'option': 'Visa'},
            'products': [
                {foreach $products as $product}
                {
                'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',
                'id': '12345',
                'price': '15.25',
                'brand': 'Google',
                'category': 'Apparel',
                'variant': 'Gray',
                'quantity': 1
                }
                {/foreach}
            ]
        }
    }
});
{/literal}
```

But it does not work.
How can i achieve this ? Thanks for the help.

Comment: "Does not work" is not really a helpful description if the problem, can you be a bit more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this.

```
var jsonObj = [];
    for(var i=0; i<products.length; i++){
        var item = {};
        var position = i + 1;

        item["id"]   = products[i].id_product;
        item["name"] = products[i].name;
        item["price"] = products[i].price;
        item["brand"] = "Brodo";
        item["category"] = category.name;
        item["variant"] = products[i].name;
        item["list"] = category.name + " list";
        item["position"] = position;
        jsonObj.push(item);
    }

    var product_list = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
    dataLayer.push({
        'ecommerce': {
            'currencyCode': 'IDR',
            'products': product_list
        }
    });
```